# XSLT 2.0 / XPATH testing for parent element in specific position

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

In XSLT 2.0 and XPATH, within `<xsl:template match="lb">`, I am testing for a variety of different `case` where each case produces different HTML output (using `xsl:choose/xsl:when`).

I want to test for the following situation, where `lb` is the very first node of any sort inside `seg` element:

```
<seg><lb break="n"/>text</seg>
```

By contrast, these tests would fail:

```
<seg>text<lb break="n"/>text</seg>

<seg><foo/><lb break="n"/>text</seg>
```

I've tried combining `parent`and `position()` but it's not testing correctly.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a template matching `lb` and then using `xsl:choose/when` in my view can be solved more elegantly and compact with precise match patterns e.g. `xsl:template match="seg/node()[1][self::lb]"` would match any first child node of a `seg` parent where the child is an `lb` element. For other conditions you would set up different templates with different match patterns.

But you can use `. is parent::seg/node()[1]` inside the `xsl:template match="lb"` to write it the other way around if needed.

Comment: I understand the template elegance from an XSLT perspective. But if `lb` (=  line break in TEI:XML) is a node that requires no other template processing, and I have 5 (!) different ways to treat it and output HTML depending on location and its attributes, it seems to me the code is much more readable/debug-able and compact within `xsl:choose`?I'm trying to get a feel for subtlety in processing. Thanks.

Comment: I would very much prefer having five separate templates with five different match patterns to handle the five different ways to handle those cases but it is partly a personal preference and obviously depends also on the input/output mapping you need and in particular how processing is set up on higher levels (e.g. only one general `apply-templates` without any `select` or several ones with different select attributes).

Answer (score 1):

```
/seg/child::node()[1]/name() = 'lb'
```

check if first child is named "lb"

Comment: This does not test from the perspective of `lb`, ie `<xsl:template match="lb">`. Therefore, the XPATH should, I believe, begin with `./....`  or `parent:...` and then test the position of self?

Comment: No, because the current node of the template must be `lb` for the context I am writing. See my addition to the post for explanation of context.

Comment: I'm not sure if xpath allows backward matching if you already selected the lb element

Comment: Yes, `parent`or `ancestor` allow you to go 'backwards', or towards the root node.

Comment: what about this one? `lb/parent::seg/child::node()[1]/name() = 'lb'` - check if parent ist "seq"

Comment: and replace name()-part with a self check

Answer (score 1):

You can simply test if there are no preceding siblings:

```
<xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::node())">
```

Do note that `node()` includes comments and processing instructions too, not just elements and text.

Alternatively, if you have a template matching `seg` where you do something like this...

```
<xsl:template match="seg">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, because `<xsl:apply-templates />` is short for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />` you could use `position()` in your template

```
<xsl:when test="position() = 1">
```

This would not work if the "seg" template did `<xsl:apply-templates select="lb" />` though.

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRd for an example of the tests in action.